# Turing machine true/false questions

Tags: automata, turing-machines

```
There is a non-regular language that is recognized by a Turing Machine.
```

I believe the answer to this is true, because Turing machines can "count" computations and have a method to keep track of their previous operations.

```
A Turing Machine can have infinitely many states.
```

I believe this is true as well, but I'm not so certain why. I understand that the tape can be infinite, does this translate to an infinite number of states?

Comment: For the first question, use the pumping lemma.

Comment: Whenever someone says "non-regular language" the first example you should think of is $0^n1^n$.  But it should be clear that a Turing machine can recognize $0^n1^n$ essentially as you said, by counting the zeroes and ones. More concretely, it can erase a 0 at the beginning, then scan forward until it finds a 1 and erase that, and repeat this over and over until it runs out of 1s prematurely (reject) or until it erases the 1 corresponding to the last 0, when it should accept if that was the last 1, and reject if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a non-regular language that is recognized by a Turing machine.

Yes, see the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) for more details.

> A Turing machine can have infinitely many states.

It depends on what "states" mean:

- [Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) can be represented by a graph which nodes are called states$^1$ and edges are called transitions. Here, this graph has to be finite, that is, Turing Machine can have only finitely many states$^1$.
- Turing machine has a tape of infinite length, and so if we put different values into cells of tape, then there are infinitely many different tapes. If we would regard such tape with values, current head position, etc. as state$^2$, then there would be infinitely many of those.

That being said, without additional context meaning state$^1$ is much more probable than state$^2$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a Turing machine that has C cells that each can have S possible states. The number of states in the entire Turing machine is equal to $S^C$. If the Turing machine has an infinite number of cells, the Turing machine has $S^\infty$ states, which is equal to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think my answer to the first one is correct as well?

Comment: There is another meaning of "states" in context of Turing machines and I'm not sure you are using the right one...